# Rendering elevation data of planet_osm_line in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap, elevation, srtm

I have created a postgres data from osm data of sachsen and from NASA srtm data extracted elevation data of the same region. I have multilinestring with varying elevation data for a single road, so is it possible to display elevation by using geoserver.

From what I know there is an option of additional dimension for elevation that can be enable in geoserver with a particular column set as the attribute that corresponds to elevation in the database.
 But since my lines are multilines each road can have varying elevation points can I display varying elevation on the line.

Can this be set for multiline?

Comment: Can you explain how you want to render the elevation? As numbers, contour lines, hillshade-like colours?

Comment: I want the elevation to be indicated as a number

Comment: i want the elevation to be indicated as number, any suggestions is most welcome @AndreJ

Answer (score 1):

A road can be several kilometers long, with varying elevation along it.

I suggest to extract the vertices of the road, add the elvation from a SRTM raster to a field named `elevation` in the nodes table, and use that for labeling.

This preprocessing can be done with QGIS, using `Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Extract Nodes` and the `Point sampling Tool` plugin.